# What kind of output is this?

Tags: television, audio-adapters

I know I have seen it before, on older Tv's, was wondering what to look for to convert it to optical.[image: mystery output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing what TV it is. Since it's an RCA socket, there's a good chance that it is simply coaxial [S/PDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF), rather than optical S/PDIF (TOSLINK). If this is the case, you will need a coaxial to optical S/PDIF converter such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Mountain-Digital-Coaxial-Converter/dp/B001U7GW68). I would ignore the 3-pin connector, especially if the user guide doesn't say what it's for.

Comment: Thanks! So, literally right after posting I realised that there was a box around the Coaxial S/PDIF and felt like an idiot, cause I was definitely looking at the three pin.

Comment: @ADSquared That puzzled me at first as well. The 3-pin should have been blanked off if it's meant for technicians.